# How is idProperty used for more complex schema? Dojo dmodel

Tags: dojo

It’s not very clear how idProperty is used in the data store when building a data model.   The documentation says “If the store has a single primary key, this indicates the property to use as the identity property. The values of this property should be unique. This defaults to "id".

Is this assuming the schema from which the model is based, has a mostly flat structure?  For example an array of objects – each with an identity property?

What if the schema is not a simple array but has more complex structure starting from a single object that contains several sub levels of properties within properties.  OR is just multiple arrays on the same level where each group of arrays identify property are independent of one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A store is an extension of a collection.

A collection is the interface for a collection of items (your obect with a potentially complex schema).

You can use Custom Querying on a collection to define special queries to find your data with any subset of properties.

In short, yes you can querying your data even if it has a custom schema but you need to define a Custom Querying.

More info can be found here at the end of the article: https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Collection.md

Comment: when you change a value in the result set, does it change in the original  datastore? or do I have to put it back with the modification?

Comment: @erotavlas yes it should be but depends but what you add in your Custom Querying.

Comment: so just to be clear, if my schema isn't a flat structure (like for example a simple database table with primary key) but rather represent more complex structure like a hierarchy of objects, then I would not use the idProperty, but rather would drill down to find objects using the methods provided in Collections (like fetch and filter)?

Comment: @erotavlas yes correct, Custom Querying it enables you to do that.